# Несколько уведомлений

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Мне нужно показывать два уведомления - одно каждый день, одно каждую пятницу. Когда уведомление появляется, у то в нем отображается только заголовок, а текст не отображается из-за этого я не могу определить работают ли оба уведомления или это только одно из них. Если включить только одно уведомление, то все работает хорошо. Сначала я пробовал создать два `PendingIntent` с одним `BroadcastReceiver`. Потом решил что проблема в одном ресивере, создал еще один, но проблема не решилась. Почему не показывает сообщения, у меня какие-то ошибки в коде?

Включаю уведомления:

```
protected void enableNotificationAlarm(){
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    everydayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SplashScreen.this, 2020, alarmIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    long intervalDay = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), intervalDay
            , everydayPendingIntent);
    Intent fridayIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NotificationReceiverFriday.class);
    fridayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SplashScreen.this, 2021, fridayIntent, 0);
    Calendar friday = Calendar.getInstance();
    friday.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    friday.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
    friday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    friday.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    long intervalWeek = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, friday.getTimeInMillis(), intervalWeek
            , everydayPendingIntent);
}
```

Ресиверы:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityMain.class);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_launcher_icon);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary));
    }
    builder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(1000);
    builder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra(context.getResources().getString(R.string.every_day_notification)));
    builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rand, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        notification = builder.build();
    }
    notificationManager.notify(rand, notification);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Получено уведомление от NotificationReceiver ");
} }

public class NotificationReceiverFriday extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityMain.class);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_launcher_icon);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary));
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(2000);
    builder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra(context.getResources().getString(R.string.friday_notification)));
    builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rand, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        notification = builder.build();
    }
    notificationManager.notify(rand, notification);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Получено уведомление от NotificationReceiver ");
} }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или у вас у уведомления есть хоть что-то и оно не null только если вы запускаете на `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN`? Зачем это?

Comment: Положите в разные `intent` различные `extras`, достаньте их и выведите в логи `Log.d("TAG",intent.getStringExtras("alarmType"));` для того, чтобы определить работают ли оба. Ну или назначьте на время разное.

Comment: @IEVGEN Я пробовал выводить extra в уведомлении, но у меня не получилось. Не знаю решит ли что-то вывод   extra в лог, но сейчас, на всякий случай попробую.